# Swipe option left to right for multiple rows at a time

Tags: jquery-ui

I have 10 columns and 10rows, 1 column in left side is fixed and the remaining 9 columns on the right side is swipable. If I swipe on the right hand side entire 9 columns of 10 rows need to swipe right to left.

I tried using swipe js plugin, but it has 1 row only swippa

Comment: Show what have you done so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour/